# How should I free memory allocated in a typemap for an argout array of structures?

Tags: python, swig

I am using SWIG to wrap a C library for Python.  One of the C methods takes
a pointer-to-struct buffer and number of elements to populate and fills in
the pointed-to structures.  For the Python API I want to provide just the
number of elements and the return value to be a tuple of populated structures.

```
  C     : int fill_widgets(widget_t *buffer, int num_widgets);
  Python: fill_widgets(num_widgets) -> (widget, widget,...)
```

I have written typemaps that have that working as I want - the typemaps allocate
a buffer based on the Python input argument, pass the buffer to the C method,
convert it to a Python tuple, then return the tuple of widgets.  But I can't figure out
if/when/how I need to free memory that is allocated in my typemap.

I originally included a freearg typemap to free the buffer when the wrapper
function exits, but I believe the structures returned to Python are still using
the physical memory (i.e. the memory isn't copied, I just get a proxy pointer
that is using the same buffer).  I also tried setting the SWIG_POINTER_OWN flag
when creating the proxy objects (via SWIG_NewPointerObj), but since I'm creating
a proxy pointer to each element in the buffer it doesn't make sense to free them
all.  In both of these cases Python eventually ends up segfaulting on a later
free() call.

So without using freearg in the typemap or SWIG_POINTER_OWN when creating the proxy,
how do I free the memory when the Python tuple-of-structs goes out of scope?

Here is a bare-bones SWIG interface that demonstrates what I have:

```
%module "test"

%typemap (in, numinputs=1) (BUF, NUM){
    $2 = PyInt_AsLong($input);
    $1 = ($1_type)calloc($2, sizeof($*1_type));
}

%typemap (argout) (BUF, NUM){
    PyObject *tpl = PyTuple_New($2);
    for ($2_ltype i=0; i<$2; i++)
    {
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tpl, i, SWIG_NewPointerObj(&$1[i], $1_descriptor, 0));
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, tpl);
}

%typemap (freearg) (BUF, NUM){
    //free($1);
}

%apply (BUF, NUM) {(widget_t *buf, int num_widgets)};

%inline {
typedef struct {int a; int b;} widget_t;

int fill_widgets(widget_t *buf, int num_widgets)
{
    for(int i=0; i<num_widgets; i++)
    {
        buf[i].a = i;
        buf[i].b = 2*i;
    }
    return num_widgets;
}
}
```

And an example to build/run:

```
$ swig -python test.i
$ gcc -I/path/to/python2.7 -shared -lpython2.7 test_wrap.c  -o _test.so
$ python
>>> import test
>>> _,widgets = test.fill_widgets(4)
>>> for w in widgets: print w.a, w.b
... 
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
>>>
```

Example usage of fill_widgets from C:

```
int main()
{
    widget_t widgets[10];  // or widget_t *widgets = calloc(10, sizeof(widget_t))
    fill_widgets(widgets, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that makes this interesting is that you've got 1 buffer, but created N Python proxy objects, all of which live in that single buffer.

Assuming you're not willing to entertain copying objects out of that buffer so you get 1:1 allocation to Python proxy object mapping and then disposing of the original buffer we've got basically one solution to work towards. The aim here is to make sure that each of the Python objects also hold a reference to the object that owns the memory. In so doing we can keep the reference count high and only release the memory once it's certain that nobody can possibly still be pointing to it.

The simplest solution to do that is to set SWIG_POINTER_OWN for the first object in the buffer (i.e. the one who's pointer really references the memory you get back from `calloc`) and then have every other proxy object not own the memory, but hold a reference to the one that does.

To do implement this we make two changes to your argout typemap. Firstly we set SWIG_POINTER_OWN only for the first element of the tuple. Secondly we call `PyObject_SetAttrString` for all but the first item to keep a reference around. So it ends up looking like this:

```
%typemap (argout) (BUF, NUM){
    PyObject *tpl = PyTuple_New($2);
    for ($2_ltype i=0; i<$2; i++)
    {
        PyObject *item = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&$1[i], $1_descriptor, 0==i?SWIG_POINTER_OWN:0);
        if (i) {
            PyObject_SetAttrString(item,"_buffer",PyTuple_GET_ITEM(tpl, 0));
        } 
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tpl, i, item);
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, tpl);
}
```

We can check the reference counts are as expected interactively:

```
In [1]: import test

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: a,b=test.fill_widgets(20)

In [4]: sys.getrefcount(b[0])
Out[4]: 21

In [5]: sys.getrefcount(b[1])
Out[5]: 2

In [6]: b[1]._buffer
Out[6]: <test.widget_t; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'widget_t *' at 0xb2118d10> >

In [7]: b[1]._buffer == b[0]
Out[7]: True

In [8]: x,y,z = b[0:3]

In [9]: del a

In [10]: del b

In [11]: sys.getrefcount(x)
Out[11]: 4

In [12]: sys.getrefcount(y)
Out[12]: 2

In [13]: sys.getrefcount(z)
Out[13]: 2

In [14]: del x

In [15]: sys.getrefcount(y._buffer)
Out[15]: 3
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  I had considered setting SWIG_POINTER_OWN for just the first object, but couldn't figure out then how to avoid freeing before all the objects were descoped - I hadn't thought of keeping references to the first one.

Comment: "Assuming you're not willing to entertain copying objects..."  This didn't even occur to me!  I guess I would just malloc and memcpy each element inside the loop and set SWIG_POINTER_OWN for each one. Then release the original buffer for  a clean exit.